# JavaScript RegEx - Dynamic field loaded with hex OR empty string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found many different ways to look at the regex for a field to see if it's a hex value, and they are all working as such. What I am struggling with is how to keep a regEx valid if there is nothing in the field.

This one handles #000000 & #000 just fine if the field was populated, but gives an invalid response when the field loads with no value:

```
/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/
```

Same as above, but here I can focus on the field and leave it empty and the pattern is valid:

```
/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)|^\0*$/
```

The ideal regEx that I am having a hard time with is valid if the field is loaded with the following values:

```
<input type="color" value="#ffffff" pattern="regEx" placeholder="#ffffff">
<input type="color" value="#fff" pattern="regEx" placeholder="#ffffff">
<input type="color" value="" pattern="regEx" placeholder="ffffff">
```

Comment: What is `null`? Is it really a `null` literal or a string `'null'`?

Comment: How would you be running a regexp against a null value?

Comment: That's a good question. I've unfortunately not had the pleasure of working with RegEx much. I just know the problem that I am trying to solve... which is to not complain if the text field is empty on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by null you mean an empty string then you can compare using

```
/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)|(^$)/
```

However, if by null you actually mean `null` you will have to check for that beforehand.
Note that the use of `!=` instead of `!==` is intentional, as this comparison will catch both `null` and `undefined`.

```
if (inputString != null) {...}
```

Comment: Do you know, when a text input is loaded to the dom and doesn't have any content in it, but does have a placeholder attribute, is that input an empty string, or null? I suppose empty string.

Comment: The final thing to note here is that I had to add lower-case checks /(^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}$)|(^$)/ . Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score -2):

You can use groups and the optional quantifier `?`:

```
/^(?:#[0-9A-F]{3}(?:[0-9A-F]{3})?)?$/
```

Comment: @epascarello: what's your problem?

Comment: I asked a valid question, how does that help? Not sure how ignoring everything when there is no match helps with this question.

Comment: @epascarello: you have downvote my answer less than 1 second after I post it, so I repeat the question: What is your problem?*

Comment: I was not the one that downvoted it. I downvoted when you popped an attitude. I still wonder how this helps with a null value.

Comment: @espascarello: in this case, I'm sorry for you. But the fact is here, someone has downvoted my answer, before reading it (whatever the answer can be). And my attitude is appropriate in this case.